# Why do Fragments require a transaction?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I'm wondering why, unlike `Activity`, a `Fragment` requires that we put it in a transaction. Does it have something to do with the transition animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transaction groups *all* UI changes so that they are performed by the `FragmentManager` at the same time (while possibly also being performance-optimized). Unlike an activity - which deals with the whole screens at once - this typically involves updating various parts of the screen simultaneously.

Certainly this could be achieved manually as well, but the concept of transactions makes implementation *much* easier.

Quote from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions):

> Each transaction is a set of changes that you want to perform at the
>   same time. You can set up all the changes you want to perform for a
>   given transaction using methods such as add(), remove(), and
>   replace(). Then, to apply the transaction to the activity, you must
>   call commit().